# Flutter Amplify S3 setup error, amplifyconfiguration.json

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm starting a project with Amplify S3 storage. I have followed many tutorials and example projects.

I downloaded this sample project:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/tree/main/example

But I get the following error, when caled Amplify.configue(amplifyconfig):

E/flutter ( 5798): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: AnalyticsException(message: Unable to read appId or region from the amplify configuration json., recoverySuggestion: Make sure amplifyconfiguration.json is a valid json object in expected format. Please take a look at the documentation for expected format of amplifyconfiguration.json., underlyingException: org.json.JSONException: No value for pinpointAnalytics)
E/flutter ( 5798): #0      AmplifyClass.configure (package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart:171:9)
E/flutter ( 5798): 
E/flutter ( 5798): #1      _MyAppState._initAmplifyFlutter (package:sample_app/main.dart:65:7)
E/flutter ( 5798): 
E/flutter ( 5798):

This is some of the code:

```
 @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAmplifyFlutter();
  }

  void _initAmplifyFlutter() async {
    AmplifyAuthCognito auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();
    AmplifyStorageS3 storage = AmplifyStorageS3();
    AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint analytics = AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint();

    Amplify.addPlugins([auth, storage, analytics]);

    // Initialize AmplifyFlutter
    try {
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
      print(
          "Amplify was already configured. Looks like app restarted on android.");
    }

    setState(() {
      _isAmplifyConfigured = true;
    });
  }
```

Also, my amplifyconfiguation.dart seems to look fine;

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": "us-east-1:b9741a22-5ce7-44e6-807d-43ac31244d3b",
                            "Region": "us-east-1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "us-east-1_xTO13zNaS",
                        "AppClientId": "3im526imsnhcl9rugc3t8c70tn",
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
                        "loginMechanisms": [
                            "PREFERRED_USERNAME"
                        ],
                        "signupAttributes": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ],
                        "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                            "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                            "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
                        },
                        "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                        "mfaTypes": [
                            "SMS"
                        ],
                        "verificationMechanisms": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "S3TransferUtility": {
                    "Default": {
                        "Bucket": "demobucket225218-dev",
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "storage": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsS3StoragePlugin": {
                "bucket": "demobucket225218-dev",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "defaultAccessLevel": "guest"
            }
        }
    }
}''';
```

I have run:

```
  amplify add auth
   amplify add storage
   amplify push
```

Here are my dependancies in pubspec.yaml

```
  file_picker: ^4.0.0
  amplify_flutter: 0.2.7
  amplify_analytics_pinpoint: 0.2.7
  amplify_auth_cognito: 0.2.7
  amplify_storage_s3: 0.2.7
```

Still no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never added analytics to your project. You did

```
 amplify add auth
   amplify add storage
   amplify push
```

But you didn't add analytics.

also, if you check your amplifyconfiguation.dart, there is "auth" and "storage" - but no analytics.

Just comment it out and try:

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAmplifyFlutter();
  }

  void _initAmplifyFlutter() async {
    AmplifyAuthCognito auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();
    AmplifyStorageS3 storage = AmplifyStorageS3();
    //AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint analytics = AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint();

    Amplify.addPlugins([auth, storage/*, analytics*/]);

    // Initialize AmplifyFlutter
    try {
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
      print(
          "Amplify was already configured. Looks like app restarted on android.");
    }

    setState(() {
      _isAmplifyConfigured = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much